# Error: ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Running the following i got error `Error: ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression`

```
with x (id, dateN) as
(
select 1, to_date('2015-05-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
union all
select id+1, dateN+1 from x where id < 10
)
select * from x
```

I've tried different casts like to_char, as timestamp, + interval '1' day and so on but this error keeps on appearing. On Mssql it's very easy via function `dateadd('dd', 1, dateN)` but here that's not very obvious how to accomplish that.

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: i think it's date, but i tried it to be timestamp also. Oh, sorry i was mistaken, it's dateN.

Comment: are you trying to generate a series of dates?

Comment: i'm, the each next generated date shoud be one day more the previous, the initial one generates in the first select.

Comment: What you've shown works (in 11gR2; which you must be on I think or you would get ORA-32033); so what is in your `where` clause, to limit the recursion? Or is there more to your real query that you haven't shown?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production, where clause is arbitrary, not a date.

Comment: What do you mean by 'arbitrary'? It has to have some limit or it would try to generate every date in the future, until it failed after 9999-12-31. My point is, the error seems to be in something you haven't shown. This (and vkp's limit; and your edited version) work fine in 11.2.0.4. I don't recall a bug like this, though recursive CTE was new in 11.2.0.1, so it's possible... Or maybe your client is mangling it? Where are you running this?

Comment: i made correction, it's still not work with simple condition like that.

Comment: i'm running it from squirell, if u mean this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on the base release this looks like but 11840579. You may be able to work around it by casting the value - it shouldn't be necessary, but that's bugs for you:

```
with x (id, dateN) as
(
  select 1, cast(to_date('2015-05-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as date) from dual
  union all
  select id+1, dateN+1 from x where id < 10
)
select * from x;
```

Including extra elements in the conversion is a bit pointless; personally I prefer date literals anyway:

```
with x (id, dateN) as
(
  select 1, cast(date '2015-05-01' as date) from dual
  union all
  select id+1, dateN+1 from x where id < 10
)
select * from x;
```

The two values, `date '2015-01-01'` and `cast(date '2015-05-01' as date)` are slightly different types, with different internal representations, which seems to be causing the problem:

```
select dump(date '2015-05-01', 16) as d1, dump(cast(date '2015-05-01' as date), 16) as d2
from dual;

D1                               D2                             
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
Typ=13 Len=8: df,7,5,1,0,0,0,0   Typ=12 Len=7: 78,73,5,1,1,1,1
```

However there's a second part to the bug which is that it can return the wrong results. If you can't patch up to avoid the problem, you could use the older hierarchical-query approach:

```
select level as id, date '2015-05-01' + level - 1 as dateN
from dual
connect by level < 10;
```

Comment: Now it works but dates are in descending order:
2015-05-01 00:00:00.0
2015-04-30 00:00:00.0
2015-04-29 00:00:00.0

Comment: Ah yes... you need to read the full bug description on My Oracle Support. I don't think there's a workaround for that, aside from patching. You could talk to your DBA (if you have a support contract, that is).

Comment: @Dmitrii - added alternative way to get the dates, in case you can't patch this bug.

Comment: yeah, connect by, has already been searching for it while got notification, thx a lot.