# Convert each date range into each day row Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table that looks like this

```
 From_date      To_date        EMP_Cod
 2013-01-01     2013-01-04      5150
 2013-01-05     2013-01-06      5151
```

How can I make it be returned like this...

```
      Date         EMP_Cod 
    2013-01-01      5150 
    2013-01-02      5150 
    2013-01-03      5150
    2013-01-04      5150
    2013-01-05      5151
    2013-01-06      5151
```

### i taken this method but not succeeded

```
    select * FROM emp_vac;
with nums as (
SELECT level-1 daystoadd
form dual 
connect by level <= 60
)
select from_date + daystoadd thedate
from emp_vac
cross join nums
where emp_vac.to_date - emp_vac.from_date + 1 > daystoadd and (emp_ser='5150')
;
```

give me Error at Command Line:3 Column:25

please help i'm beginner

Comment: What error did it give you? (You have `form` instead of `from` but not sure if you've retyped this for posting...)

Answer (score 1):

The only obvious error in your posted code is that you have `form dual` instead of `from dual`. But with that fixed it doesn't give the output you want, quite, as you are only getting the dates and only for one employee:

```
THEDATE   
----------
2013-01-01
2013-01-02
2013-01-03
2013-01-04
```

You could remove the filter and add the `emp_ser` value though:

```
with nums as (
SELECT level-1 daystoadd
from dual 
connect by level <= 60
)
select from_date + daystoadd thedate, emp_ser
from emp_vac
cross join nums
where emp_vac.to_date - emp_vac.from_date + 1 > daystoadd -- and (emp_ser='5150')
order by emp_ser, thedate;

THEDATE       EMP_SER
---------- ----------
2013-01-01       5150
2013-01-02       5150
2013-01-03       5150
2013-01-04       5150
2013-01-05       5151
2013-01-06       5151
```

The hard limit of 60 days is a little awkward though. You could get the same result with a single hierarchical query:

```
select from_date + level - 1 as vac_date, emp_ser
from emp_vac
connect by emp_ser = prior emp_ser
and level <= to_date - from_date + 1
and prior dbms_random.value is not null;

VAC_DATE      EMP_SER
---------- ----------
2013-01-01       5150
2013-01-02       5150
2013-01-03       5150
2013-01-04       5150
2013-01-05       5151
2013-01-06       5151
```

which needs the awkward call to a non-deterministic function (`dbms_random.value` in this case, but you could use others) to work properly for multiple source rows; or with [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6):

```
with rcte (vac_date, to_date, emp_ser) as (
  select from_date, to_date, emp_ser
  from emp_vac
  union all
  select vac_date + 1, to_date, emp_ser
  from rcte
  where vac_date < to_date
)
select vac_date, emp_ser
from rcte
order by emp_ser, vac_date;

VAC_DATE      EMP_SER
---------- ----------
2013-01-01       5150
2013-01-02       5150
2013-01-03       5150
2013-01-04       5150
2013-01-05       5151
2013-01-06       5151
```

Here the anchor member gets the start date of each record, and the recursive member  adds a day at a time until it reaches the end date. (Incidentally, I'd advise against using a function name like `to_date` as a column name - it's legal but confusing.)

Of course, if the vacation period spans a weekend or other holiday then all of these approaches will include those non-work days, which might not really be what you want. Excluding weekends would be relatively simple, but to exclude other holidays you would need a look-up table that identifies those dates.

---

As @PonderStibbons noted in a comment, there is a bug with dates and recursive CTEs in some versions (possibly just 11.2.0.1 and 11.2.0.2 - seems to be bug 11840579 which is shown as fixed in 11.2.0.3 in MoS); this is Ponder's workaround using numbers instead of dates for the recursive member limit:

```
with rcte (rn, diff, from_date, emp_ser) as (
  select 1, trunc(to_date - from_date), from_date, emp_ser from emp_vac
  union all
  select rn + 1, diff, from_date, emp_ser from rcte where rn <= diff )
select from_date + rn - 1 vac_date, emp_ser
from rcte
order by emp_ser, vac_date;
```

... and [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=48cae9478e0b6489073d2260681d5319) (11.2.0.2).

Comment: For some reason (dates bug) RCTE version does not work in Oracle 11. After small modification, where we operate on numbers instead of dates it works. Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=48cae9478e0b6489073d2260681d5319). Great answer anyway.

Comment: Interesting, I tested it on 11.2.0.4 and it was fine. db<>fiddle is 11.2.0.2 so I guess this is bug 11840579 which is shown as fixed in 11.2.0.3. (I've [seen this before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38015049/266304) but had forgotten about it...) Anyway, thanks for the workaround.

Comment: give me error     Error at Command Line:1 Column:10
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-32033: تبديل العمود غير مدعوم
32033. 00000 -  "unsupported column aliasing"
*Cause:    column aliasing in WITH clause is not supported yet
*Action:   specify aliasing in defintion subquery and retry

Comment: in first method it work but get all data can i filter on one person to test it ? how

Comment: @islaambahy - you must be on a version earlier than 11.2, which means you won't be able to use recursive CTEs as they were also added in that release. You'll have to use the hierarchical method (either the adapted version of yours, or the second code block with the call to `dbms_random`). If you want to test for a single person just put your `emp_ser` filter back in.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select (from_Date+r-1), emp_code1 from (
select distinct a.from_Date,a.emp_code as emp_code1 , b.emp_code as emp_code2 , b.r from  emp_vac a,  (Select emp_code, level r
From emp_vac b  
Connect By level <= (to_Date-from_Date)+1  )  b where a.emp_code=b.emp_code
) where emp_code1=emp_code2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 em_code, (to_date(end_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') - level + 1) AS days
FROM
   islaam_vca where em_code = '2222'

CONNECT BY level <= (to_date(end_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date(start_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') + 1)
order by days ASC
;
```

---

it's work i test this code and working with me